# scrolltop+clientY not working in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

```
var YPos12 = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;
```

is not working for Mozilla Firefox. Anyone can give me working example with code? Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't the following to work, I would suggest you start using jQuery or another javscript framework to help. I personally use jquery but have a look at the available [javascript frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks) out there, they make life much easier.

Completely replaced with full working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<head>
<title>Mouse Co-ordinates Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var posX;
var posY;

function mouseMovement(newEvent){
  posX=0;posY=0;
  var myEvent=(!newEvent)?window.event:newEvent;//IE:Moz
  if (myEvent.pageX){//Moz
    posX=myEvent.pageX+window.pageXOffset;
    posY=myEvent.pageY+window.pageYOffset;
  }
  else if(myEvent.clientX){//IE
    posX=myEvent.clientX+document.body.scrollLeft;
    posY=myEvent.clientY+document.body.scrollTop;
  }
  else {
    return false
  }//old browsers

  // Your X & Y values will be available here via  posX & posY
  document.getElementById('movementspan').firstChild.data='X='+posX+' Y='+posY;
}

function myClickEvent(myClick) {
  document.getElementById('clickspan').firstChild.data='X='+posX+' Y='+posY;
}
document.onmousemove=mouseMovement;
document.onclick=myClickEvent;
</script>

</head>
<body onload="init()">
Mouse Co-ordinates 
<span id="movementspan">&nbsp;</span>
<br />
Mouse co-ordinates at click 
<span id="clickspan">&nbsp;</span>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Edited above, above, output posX & posY to page somewhere, you need to add a handler for the onmousemove event

Comment: I edited the above, but to do this much easier refer to the following jquery makes life much easier http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Mouse_Position#Where_did_they_click_that_div.3F

Comment: i couldn't get "myEvent.pageX+window.pageXOffset;" value!

Comment: e.PageX & e.pageY,i am getting "undefined",since my code is dynamic